# VB.net Update MS Access from DataGridView with BindingSource

Tags: sql, vb.net, winforms, ms-access, datagridview

I have a DataGridView populated with a SQL statement that users can input data on certain columns:

```
    Me.bndDataGrid.DataSource = GetData("SELECT H.InnCode, R.RSRM, " & strCols & " E.Escalation " & _
                                           "FROM (((dbo_HotelInfo AS H " & _
                                           "INNER JOIN dbo_RSRM AS R ON H.RevMgr = R.ID) " & _
                                           "INNER JOIN dbo_SrMgr AS S ON R.SrMgr = S.ID) " & _
                                           "INNER JOIN " & strHitList & " AS L ON H.FacilityID = L.FacilityID) " & _
                                           "INNER JOIN dbo_Escalation AS E ON H.FacilityID = E.FacilityID " & _
                                           "WHERE S.ID = " & cbxSrMgr.SelectedValue.ToString)

        With Me.grdQueryResults

            .AutoGenerateColumns = True
            .DataSource = bndDataGrid
        End With
```

bndDataGrid is the BindingSource for grdQueryResults, the DataGridView. The code for GetData is commonly found on MS forums:

```
Private Shared Function GetData(ByVal sqlCommand As String) As DataTable

    Dim strConn As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source={MS Access DB Path Here};"
    Dim ctnHitList As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(strConn)
    Dim tblHitList As New DataTable

    Dim cmdHitList As New OleDbCommand(sqlCommand, ctnHitList)
    Dim adrHitList As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter()
    adrHitList.SelectCommand = cmdHitList

    tblHitList.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
    adrHitList.Fill(tblHitList)

    Return tblHitList

End Function
```

Now once users are ready to save changes I can't for the life of me figure out how to have this save correctly, mostly since the data source for the DataGridView isn't simply bound to a table.

EDIT:

OK, so I mostly overhauled my code in accordance with Crowcoder's blog page, and got a lot further with it, but now on updating I'm running into a "Concurrency violation: the UpdateCommand affected 0 of the expected 1 records" exception.  Here's the update code:

```
Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click

    Dim parInnCode As OleDbParameter = New OleDbParameter("@parInnCode", OleDbType.WChar)
    Dim parNotes As OleDbParameter = New OleDbParameter("@parNotes", OleDbType.WChar)

    parInnCode.SourceColumn = "InnCode"
    parNotes.SourceColumn = "Notes"

    Using ctnDataGrid As New OleDbConnection(getConnectionString())
        Using cmdGrid As New OleDbCommand("UPDATE (dbo_The400 AS T INNER JOIN dbo_HotelInfo AS H ON T.FacilityID = H.FacilityID) " & _
                                          "INNER JOIN dbo_RSRM AS R ON H.RevMgr = R.ID " & _
                                          "SET [Notes] = @parNotes WHERE H.InnCode = @parInnCode", ctnDataGrid)
            Using adrDataGrid As New OleDbDataAdapter()
                With adrDataGrid
                    .UpdateCommand = cmdGrid
                    With .UpdateCommand.Parameters()
                        .Add(parInnCode)
                        .Add(parNotes)
                    End With
                    grdQueryResults.EndEdit()
                    .Update(tblDataGrid)
                End With
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using

End Sub
```

tblDataGrid is declared at the Form Class level, wondering if that may be the issue or if my update query doesn't match the number of columns in the table?  Or something else?  Can't seem to find the right answer for my case :/

Comment: Usually this is done through the DataAdapter that has the Select command using the Update method. But in your case this is not possible for two reasons. The DataAdapter doesn't exist at the moment of the save because is a local variable inside the GetData method. Second reason is the fact that a Join query cannot be updated automatically. So you are left with a loop over each row and with a manual call to update the record with an Update query.

Comment: Not sure if this makes any difference but the only columns that the user can change all come from the same table, the rest of that join query is meant to display a text code rather than an ID, as well as filter to just the data that pertains to each user.  Is there a way to send the results of the DataGridView back to the database and update that way?  Like a pass-through query perhaps?

Comment: I think that the only way to update/insert is calling the DataSource (is a DataTable) GetChanges method to retrieve the list of rows changed in the grid. Then for each row you need to build an UPDATE or INSERT sql command with the values extracted by the row. It is the same logic used by the DataAdapter Update method but you need to do it manually in your code.

Comment: [I have a blog post here](https://contrivedexample.com/2015/03/14/a-basic-example-of-crud-with-datagridview-in-vb-net/) that demonstrates the basics of using data adapters and grids. As already stated you need to keep an instance of the adapter in memory and configure appropriate Update command on the adapter.

Comment: That blog post is a HUGE help.  I think my problem was procedural mostly, but I can follow right along your tutorial to at least get the proper foundation, and from there be able to fit this to my current project.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welp, at long last I figured it out.  It involved quite a bit of back end reorganizing to make it easier to connect to it via the front end .net application.  Basically I threw all manager inputs into one table and added a column that corresponds to the initiative that required their input.

From there, I could build just about everything in the Dataset Designer and set the Update command on that tableadapter to just update that one table.  Cut down the code on the main form to just a few lines that fill the datasources for the combobox columns in the datagridview.

Not an elegant coding solution, but it works!